# Generating a VERSION_STRING from major/minor/patch/build defines for use in a plist

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, macos, plist

I have a plist that is processed with a precompiled header file and in it there is the "variable" VERSION_STRING used a few times in such fields as CFBundleGetInfoString, ie the value for the key CFBundleGetInfoString is: MyProduct VERSION_STRING Copyright © 2009 MyCorp

In MyHeader.h (which is the set as the Info.plist prefix header I would like to be able to build VERSION_STRING into the form MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH.BUILD where I have

```
#define MAJOR 1
#define MINOR 0
#define PATCH 0
#define BUILD 23
```

For some reason I seem to be incapable of doing this. I might just be having one of those moments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is actually an Apple Tech Note on this and a solution to the very problem I was having. So, for anyone that may come across this and is having the same problems I was check out [Technical Note TN2175: Preprocessing Info.plist files in Xcode Using the C Preprocessor](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2007/tn2175.html)

Answer (score 0):

Take your plist file and rename it with an extra extension (perhaps a P?). Add `#include "MyHeader.h"` to the beginning of the file, and preprocess it in your build with the C preprocessor (usually `cpp`). You may need to filter out extra `#` lines, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

By default, `cpp` should output to stdout, so adding a command like this might work fine:

```
cpp myplist.plist.P | grep -v '^#' > myplist.plist
```

Comment: As part of the build process you can tell Xcode to automatically include a header file when preprocessing the Info.plist file, which is what I'm doing. The problem I've having is with properly assembling the VERSION_STRING from its components.

Comment: I have to confess I have very little experience with XCode. Forgive my ignorance of its features. Could you demonstrate how you have tried to build your `VERSION_STRING`?

Comment: No worries. The current string that exists is:

#define VERSION_NUM 1.0.0.BUILD_NUM

Where BUILD_NUM is defined as a number. This currently results in just 1.0.0.BUILD_NUM and BUILD_NUM is *not* replaced with the build number.

I would also like to replace the 1.0.0 part with the major/minor/patch defines.

Comment: How about this, then: `#define VERSION_NUM 1.0.0.##BUILD_NUM`